bottleneck in multiprocessing in python
I have a code that uses two parameters (r,t) to create a matrix H. I then find the eigenvalues of this matrix and do some computations using the eigenvalues. Now, I need to do this for many different values of (r,t), (around 200). Since each operation is independent I tried to use multiprocessing in python to have all these operations done simultaneously.
When I run the code for a single (r,t), it takes around 1.5 hours. I was under the impression that running it for 200 (r,t)s should take around the same time using multiprocessing. However, it seems t be taking significantly longer. I am well into the 2nd day of the code running. I am using my university's high performance unit so I believe there should be enough cores to assign. My code is something like below-
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

rs = np.linspace(0.5,1.5,20)
thetas = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,10)

def matrix_stuff(r,t):
#constructs a matrix H(r,t). Diagonalize and do stuff.


processes = []
rets = []
q = multiprocessing.Queue()

for i in range(len(thetas)):
    for j in range(len(rs)):
        theta = thetas[i]
        r = rs[I]
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=matrix_stuff, args = (r,theta,i,j))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

for p in processes:
    ret = q.get()
    rets.append(ret)

for p in processes:
    p.join()


#store output in deltas

deltas = np.zeros((len(rs),len(thetas)))


for ret in rets:
    # ret has format (value, i,j)
    deltas[rets[1],rets[2]] = rets[0]

np.savetxt('new_deltas.txt',deltas)

My question is then are there some other areas where my program could be getting bottlenecked that I am not considering? This my is first time using multiprocessing so I am still not very clear on the details.
Edit: I created some test scripts to check the amount of time various processes are taking. While for a generic test where the parallel process is just time.sleep(10), the parallelisation does seem to be working as intended. However, when using the following test code,
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import numpy as np

def foo():
    X = np.random.rand(2000,2000)
    eigs = np.linalg.eigvals(X)
    return eigs

def foo_q(q):
    X = np.random.rand(2000,2000)
    eigs = np.linalg.eigvals(X)
    q.put(eigs)

start_lin = time.time()
for _ in range(5):
    val = foo()
end_lin = time.time()

print('Time taken for linear process : ',(end_lin - start_lin))

q = mp.Queue()
processes = []

start_par = time.time()

for _ in range(5):
    p = mp.Process(target = foo_q, args = (q,))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    ret = q.get()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

end_par = time.time()

print('Time taken for parallel process : ',(end_par - start_par))                                                                                                      

I get-
Time taken for linear process :  15.935563564300537
Time taken for parallel process :  16.6868999004364
What is happening here?
Also, for reference, running the mp.cpu_count() function, it seem I have 192 cores available.

Your target function matrix_stuff takes only two arguments, instead of 4 from the call to Process. Likely a typo. Otherwise, I would have done it exactly the same. The code looks correct to me. You could add some debugging print-statements to see the elapsed time per process.

How many cores does the CPU you're running your code on actually have? I doubt that starting more processes than available cores gives you an actual benefit.

Since this is a CPU-bound task, you only increase throughput by parallelizing to the number of CPU cores available. Generally, if you're unclear on the details, run an experiment, perhaps with two CPU-bound tasks that each take 10s. Without MP, they would take 20s, with MP they could run in parallel and only take 10s combined. Also see [mcve], which isn't only required for many questions here but also helps you understand things.

But, based on your 2nd example, the main cpu-consuming part of your code is some numpy eigen values computing. Those are already parallelized. If you start 5 process doing so in parallel, you force each process to share the cores, and use five times less cores. So, process are 5 times slower, but you run them 5 times faster because you run them 5 by 5 in parallel. So, altogether, same overall speed. But for some overhead of course, to copy the data among processes and stuff like that. So it is quite normal that your // version is slightly slower than the normal one.

"I have 192 cores" how much ram? I would worry about running out of memory with hundreds of processes, and if you start using swap, that could majorly slow things down.

If you have 192 cores and numpy's also doing work in parallel, you may want to create a multiprocessing pool with far fewer workers than would be the default. As a starting point, try ~20 and measure that. It's not an exact science

Better to use a multiprocessing Pool.
By default, Pool() will create a number of workers equal to the value returned by os.cpu_count() In most cases this will be optimum. I would never advise creating more workers than you have CPUs. You may however want to reduce the number of workers from the default if other activity on your computer is likely to be impacted.
Here's an example using some of aspects of the OP that demonstrates a pattern that you could adapt to this particular use-case.
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def matrix_stuff(args):
    r, t = args
    ...

def genargs(rs, thetas):
    for theta in thetas:
        for r in rs:
            yield r, theta

def main():
    rs = np.linspace(0.5,1.5,20)
    thetas = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,10)
    with Pool() as pool:
        for result in pool.map(matrix_stuff, genargs(rs, thetas)):
            print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

